# Looking for an UWP container layout which wraps elements when overflowing

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm basically looking a container which is responisve and sort of like Twitter Bootstrap's scaffolding behaviour. A set of content elements where either the height or width is constant and the other dimension is not, which wraps either veritcally or horizontally when overflowing. It must also allow for scrolling if all elements does not fit the screen.

What I've tried unsucessfully is

- [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid). - Forces both dimensions to be fixed.
- [AdaptiveGridView](http://uwpcommunitytoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/controls/AdaptiveGridView/) from the UWP Community Toolkit. - Scales elements instead of allowing for scroll
- WrapPanel from [this CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463860/WinRT-Custom-WrapPanel?msg=5374728#xx5374728xx). - Crashes when put in a ScrollViewer

Any pointer to  a ready-made component is appreciated, or how to implement or alter one of the above to function for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The UWP Community Toolkit contains a [WrapPanel control](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/WrapPanel/) which does what you describe.